# retrieve JSON data from mysql server and storing it to object in android

Tags: android, mysql, json, android-volley, store

I'm new with android and mySQL server. I'm writing an app that should retrieve JSON data from the server and then stores the data to an object "Court". I'm using Volley library. but When ever I tries to store it and use it outside of "onRespons" Method I get that the object or String is null.

This is what I tried So far.

DatabaseConnection.java UPDATED !!!

```
public class DataBaseConnection extends AppCompatActivity {


String temp;
Court court;
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        court = new Court();
    }

public String retrive(final Context context, final String newURL) {
    final RequestQueue request;
    request = newRequestQueue(context);



    Response.Listener<String> sendR = new Response.Listener<String>() {
        //Court[] courts;







        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {



            sharedResponse(response);

            court.setName(response);




        }



    };

    System.out.println(court.getName());

    Response.ErrorListener errorr = new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            System.out.println("There is an error");
            System.out.println(error.getMessage());
        }
    };

    StringRequest sender = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, newURL,sendR,errorr) {

        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> parameters = new HashMap<String, String>();
            parameters.put("test", "test");

            return parameters;

        }
    };



    request.add(sender);
    return court.getName();
}


private void sharedResponse(String response) {
    SharedPreferences m = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = m.edit();
    editor.putString("Response", response);
    editor.commit();
}
}
```

And this is the Lising Class:

```
public class Listing extends AppCompatActivity {

private  String url = "http://192.168.1.106/list/list.php";


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_listing);
    String JSON="";


    DataBaseConnection connect = new DataBaseConnection();
    JSON = connect.retrive(getApplicationContext(), url);

    System.out.println("first time"+JSON);

    SharedPreferences m = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    JSON = m.getString("Response", "");

    System.out.println("Second time"+JSON);

}
}
```

As you see I tried with simple return value and with SharedPrefrences also I tried it with Intent. but all of them didn't work with me. As of the Log Cat shows some errors about NULLPointerException.

LogCat:

```
    12-05 11:45:40.815 30821-30821/com.saihatandroid.owen.lising I/System.out: first time
12-05 11:45:40.817 30821-30821/com.saihatandroid.owen.lising I/System.out: Second time
12-05 11:45:40.865 30821-30852/com.saihatandroid.owen.lising I/Adreno: QUALCOMM build                   : 4d8478c, I7b6ba47bd6
                                                                       Build Date                       : 02/09/16
                                                                       OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: XE031.07.00.01
                                                                       Local Branch                     : mybranch18178856
                                                                       Remote Branch                    : quic/LA.HB.1.3.1_rb1.11
                                                                       Remote Branch                    : NONE
                                                                       Reconstruct Branch               : NOTHING

12-05 11:45:41.025 30821-30821/com.saihatandroid.owen.lising E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                               Process: com.saihatandroid.owen.lising, PID: 30821
                                                                               java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Context.getPackageName()' on a null object reference
                                                                                   at android.content.ContextWrapper.getPackageName(ContextWrapper.java:133)
                                                                                   at android.preference.PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferencesName(PreferenceManager.java:375)
                                                                                   at android.preference.PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(PreferenceManager.java:370)
                                                                                   at com.saihatandroid.owen.lising.DataBaseConnection.sharedResponse(DataBaseConnection.java:148)
                                                                                   at com.saihatandroid.owen.lising.DataBaseConnection.access$000(DataBaseConnection.java:44)
                                                                                   at com.saihatandroid.owen.lising.DataBaseConnection$1.onResponse(DataBaseConnection.java:75)
                                                                                   at com.saihatandroid.owen.lising.DataBaseConnection$1.onResponse(DataBaseConnection.java:61)
                                                                                   at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:60)
                                                                                   at com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest.deliverResponse(StringRequest.java:30)
                                                                                   at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:99)
                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:168)
                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5885)
                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:819)
                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:709)
```

Also Found this Error At the bottom of the Logcat

```
D/Process: com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$UncaughtHandler.uncaughtException:113 java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException:693 java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException:690
```

I need your Help I couldn't find anything in the web that relate to it and I tried all the option what I found. 
Thanks

Comment: ``NullPointerException``  android.content.Context.getPackageName()

Comment: check your php any item cannot display?

Comment: Why don't u initialize court = new Court(); in onCreate() of DataBaseConnection Activity rather than in that constructor. And remove the DataBaseConnection constructor and try

Comment: @Owen_mhy I'm quite confused with your DataBaseConnection class  - extends AppCompatActivity is it intentional or by mistake I don't know much abt Volley library though. Can u double check that DataBaseConnection class implementation?

Comment: @DonaldWu There is no problem with PHP the problem I could see the response from my PHP but only in onRespons method.

Comment: @Raghavendra Tried to initialize it on onCreate Method the Same

Comment: @Owen_mhy can u post your updated DataBaseConnection class?

Comment: @Raghavendra I used to have some methods that I use AppCompatActivity but I don't need it and I took it but still the same error

Comment: @Owen_mhy post your latest DataBaseConnection class?

Comment: Just Updated The Class

Comment: @Owen_mhy yes DataBaseConnection connect = new DataBaseConnection(); this line will fail. Can u tell me what is the specific usage of class DataBaseConnection ? If there is no use for u then why don't u use the methods of DataBaseConnection in Listing directly?

Comment: @Raghavendra I have manged to run the app without an error but the output is still null

Comment: @Owen_mhy issue is solved?

Comment: @Raghavendra Nope Because I could 't get the output of data outside 'code ' Response.Listener<String> sendR = new Response.Listener<String>() { Override public void onResponse(String response) { // here I could see the output. court.setName(response); System.out.println(court.getName()); } }; //here it should print the response from the server just like above but it prints "" empty string and here is my original problem System.out.println(court.getName());

Comment: @Owen_mhy so when u debig you can see response data at court.setName(response); this line.?